# python UI app hangs while updating stdout output to UI using subprocess.Popen in a for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, subprocess, pyqt4

I'm running subprocess.Popen() to call a commandline tool which prints it's output to console like so:

```
[app] : Initializing...
[app] : Starting process
[app] : .............
[app] : .............
[app] : Extracting information
[app] : Downloading information
[app] : 100% completed              
[app] : Saving file to disk
[app] : Completed
```

Now i'm trying to capture the output so I can show this output to my python UI application in realtime. I'm capturing the output like so:

```
cmd = "..."
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout:
    self.status.showmsg(str(line.rstrip()))
    p.stdout.flush()
```

**The problem:** The output are displayed on my UI correctly until it reaches that output line where it shows the percentage of process completed(100% in the example). This is where the UI hangs and the gradual increase of the % is not displayed or any output thereafter. The program is running correctly in the background though(does its thing) and when it's 100% complete, the UI unfreezes.

What am I doing wrong here? Looks to me that (%) output is also another loop and failing there but I don't know why or how to go about handling this in python.

Thanks for the valuable suggestions!

Comment: Try `QtGui.qApp.processEvents()` at the end of the loop.

Comment: thanks but that didn't work either

Comment: In that case, do the work in a separate thread and use a custom signal to send the output to the gui. Or use `QProcess` instead of subprocess.

Comment: Could try threading but for a small application of about 100 lines of code, I'm reluctant to use threading

Comment: Why? A threaded solution would be quite simple - see my answer for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Run the worker process in a separate thread and send the data back to the gui using a custom signal. Here's a very basic demo script:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    dataReceived = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        # subprocess stuff goes here
        for step in range(6):
            self.sleep(1)
            self.dataReceived.emit('data received: %d' % step)

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
        self.thread = Thread(self)
        self.thread.dataReceived.connect(self.statusBar().showMessage)

    def handleButton(self):
        if not self.thread.isRunning():
            self.statusBar().showMessage('starting...')
            self.thread.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.thread.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(200, 60)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```